# How to implement an exception handler with stack trace in C++

Tags: c++, exception, seh

I have to implement an exception handler with the call trace feature.
In the current implementation I use SEH with mingw compiler but it I am not able to implement stack trace since the stack is unwound when the control comes to my handler.
Is there any way of preserving the call  stack and accessing it in the handler